# Scrape oddsportal information

Tags: javascript, parsing, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, scrape

I'm using Python 3.5 and actually I'm focusing into webscraping with BeautifulSoup/lxml/Selenium/PhantomJS

I'm just trying to scrape all data that I need just to hack with Python code.

I can easily scrape information from Static HTML url with BeautifulSoup.
I've recently discovered how to take information from dynamic url too, using the Network Tab on Chrome and see under XHR option the HTTPrequest that comes out.
It usually gives me the html code generated from JS and in this case I can continue with regular expression scraping it with BS4.
But actually i'm working in a new project about scraping odds from www.oddsportal.com
In this case I'm really confused how to proceed cause under XHR I can't find a valid thing to continue scraping.
Trying and retrying, I figured out that I can scrape the information from an url like that:

For example my link is:
http://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league/tottenham-sunderland-UBtChnLa/

The link that I found really interesting is:

http://fb.oddsportal.com/feed/match/1-1-UBtChnLa-1-2-yjc11.dat?_=1452760985069

Here you can find every odds that I need but when I try to scrape it it gives me error like:

globals.jsonpCallback

I understand that I have to learn json library in python but I'm really confused about how to proceed. 
Can you please help me, explaining all? I'm really trying to focus in this kind of projects so I'd like to understand more but I know that my knownledge about that is quite low actually.
Thanks for any informations!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried scraping the html using xpath? You might find it easier rather than using regex. Also you might want to have a look at HtmlAgilityPack for C# which is perfect for web scraping.

Answer (score 0):

(R rather than python)
I've been struggling with a similar issue and having sorted it out after a long while wrapped the solution as an R package. I wonder if this is similar enough to port to python.
https://github.com/ikashnitsky/oddor